# How to make Scrollable the Storyboard Scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

i am using storyboard scrollview but its didn't scroll ,how to make it as scrollable.

**This is my code**

```
-(void)scrollView
{
    self.scrollViewBtn.pagingEnabled=YES;
    self.scrollViewBtn.scrollEnabled=YES;
    for(int i=0;i<[[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"name"]count];i++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x=self.scrollViewBtn.frame.size.width *i;
        frame.origin.y=0;
        frame.size=self.scrollViewBtn.frame.size;
        UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrFullSubCategory objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.scrollViewBtn addSubview:btn];
        btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
        btn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        length = [[arrFullSubCategory valueForKey:@"name"] count];


    }
    self.scrollViewBtn.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.scrollViewBtn.frame.size.width *length, self.scrollViewBtn.frame.size.height-60);
}
```

Comment: Is userInteractionEnabled on scrollViewBtn ?

Comment: yes its enable and delegate also perfectly set. @akashsr

Comment: Where are you declaring the length variable ?

Comment: Did you set the scrollview to scroll horizontally?

Comment: log ur content size, if it is less than than the scroll view, it wont scroll. Content size should be more than scroll view

Comment: @JasonNam yes i have set but didn't scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the attributes inspector?

[image: Attributes inspector]

Also you can check the buttons are added appropriately by using Xcode layout debugging tool

[Xcode Debugging Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html)